# How to get a customer's email address and transaction subject from the Authorize.net "unsettled transactions" API?

Tags: php, api, transactions, authorize.net

I am using the Authorize.net API for PHP with the help of some of the online examples to iterate through all the transactions of today (or last 24 hours). So far I'm only able to obtain the submit time and the transaction amount (aka settle amount). How can I get the email of the customer as well as the transaction subject/description?

Inside the loop where the two spots are marked "/*  HERE */" I've tried several ways with no luck. What is the correct syntax?

```
require 'autoload.php';
require_once 'SampleCodeConstants.php';
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

/* Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
retrieved from the constants file */
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
$merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

// Set the transaction's refId
$refId = 'ref' . time();

$request = new AnetAPI\GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest();
$request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);

$controller = new AnetController\GetUnsettledTransactionListController($request);
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);

if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == 'Ok')) {
    if (null != $response->getTransactions()) {
        foreach($response->getTransactions() as $tx) {
            echo 'SUCCESS: TransactionID: ' . $tx->getTransId() . "\n";

            $request = new AnetAPI\GetTransactionDetailsRequest();
            $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
            $request->setTransId($tx->getTransId());

            $controller = new AnetController\GetTransactionDetailsController($request);
            $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);

            echo "Submitted on (Local): " . date_format($tx->getSubmitTimeLocal(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
            echo "Settle amount: " . number_format($tx->getSettleAmount(), 2, '.', '') . "\n";
            echo "Email: " . /* HERE */ . "\n";
            echo "Transaction subject: " . /* HERE */ . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No unsettled transactions for the merchant.' . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'ERROR :  Invalid response' . "\n";
    $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
    echo 'Response : ' . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . ' ' .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
}

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*getUnsettledTransactionListRequest*](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-unsettled-transaction-list) does not return customer email nor order description, you can obtain these fields (for a given transaction), if you call [*getTransactionDetailsRequest*](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-details), you can add the following to your getTransactiondetails script to get email/description:

- $response->getTransaction()->getCustomer()->getEmail()
- $response->getTransaction()->getOrder()->getDescription()

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you Mansour! One more quick question while we're at it: how about getting the originating website the transaction was done on, do you know how I can get that?

Comment: I don't know what is your integration flow, but if you currently don't have any data that can differentiate your transaction source, you can explore using _userFields_ which are merchant defined data that can be passed within _createTransaction_ requests.

Comment: It's through WP/WooCommerce. I tried searching for "userFields" and didn't find any relevant documentation in the API.

Comment: Check the request field description section under [Charge a credit card](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-credit-card) or [Authorized a credit card](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-authorize-a-credit-card) requests in Authorize.Net API reference {_userFields: These elements may be used to pass through information, such as session IDs and order details. ..._}